# How do I perform actions on a huge Illustrator document that is taking very long to process?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to separate my complex Illustrator artwork by colors but the file is very large (303mb) which is making it difficult for the program to perform each action. Even just selecting all of the expanded elements in the document (so I can trim them) is taking over an hour (it says 'not responding' in the header but I'm still waiting). To reduce the file size a bit, I've used VectorFirstAid to get rid of unnecessary points. However, performing each action is still taking way too long and I'm wondering if there is another way I can do these actions quicker. As of now, all of the elements are expanded and merged under one layer. I am trying to select all of the elements so I can trim them and separate the whole thing by colors.